# how do i change the value of an input field with jquery?

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to use jquery to change the value of an input text box, but it's not working,
here is my code...

```
    <form method="get">
            <input id="temp" type="text" name="here" value="temp value" />
            <input class="form" type="radio" value="1" name="someForm" /> Enter something
            Here: <input id="input" type="text" name="here" value="test value" />
    </form>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.form').click(function () {
            var newvalue = $("#input").val();
            $("#temp").val(newvalue);
            $("#input").val($("#temp").val());
        });
    });

</script>
```

the value of the "#input" text box is not changing!!!!!!
why is that???
what am i missing???
thanks a 10 million in advance
p.s. the value of the text box is changing, but the value attribute of the input is NOT!!!
even if i write...

```
var value = $("#temp").val();
$("#input").attr("value", value);
```

Comment: you're missing a hash sign (`#`), I'd say

Comment: What's the goal? It looks like there are several little problems, any of which could cause whatever problem you're seeing, but without knowing exactly what the end result you're looking for is I don't think anyone will give the answer you need.

Comment: my goal is to enter some text, and change the "value" attribute of the "#input" textbox to the entered value.

Comment: No that's a little piece of your implementation :) I think we should know your goal is, independant of the selector syntax you're using. What I see is that when the user clicks the radion button you're reading the `id="input"` element's value, setting the `id="temp"` input's value to the same, and then setting the `id="input"` input's value to the same again. That seems weird; how does the last step (`$("#input").val($("#temp").val());`) contribute to what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

**The value is not changing because you assign the value that `#input` already has.**

---

Have a closer look:

```
var newvalue = $("#input").val();
$("#temp").val(newvalue);
$("#input").val($("#temp").val());
```

1. Let value of `#input` be `foo`.
2. You assign `newvalue = value of #input = 'foo'`
3. You set the value of `#temp`:
   `value of #temp = newvalue = value of #input = 'foo'`
4. You set the value of `#input`:
   `value of #input = value of #temp  = newvalue = value of #input = 'foo'`

So depending on which field should get which value you have to change this ;)

Comment: That was the problem in the logic.. previously Lina was asking about this syntax..
$("input").val($(temp).val());

So now u r right...After correcting the proper syntax..!!!

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting `input` not `#input` so you are setting the value of the first `<input>` not the element with `id="input"`.

The first input is `#temp` so you are setting the value of that input to its current value.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#input").val($('#temp').val());
```

instead of:

```
$("input").val($(temp).val());
```

Comment: ok, the text value is changing, what about the "value" attribute, it will not change!!!!
even if i write...
var x = $("temp").val();
("#input").attr("value", "x");